# call back function are called before the request is finished

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a like button similar to the one in twitter, which calls a function which deals with the requests and in the call back function which increases the number of likes and change liked bool to true and the button changed to unliked button, the problem is if I clicked fast in the like button the number of likes increases and decreases more than the one user which is allowed

I have tried to put delay 1 second inside the call back function and outside it but it didn't have the best effect

```
likeDecision(kweek: Kweek): void {
    // not in my profile
    if (this.callCommonFunc) {
      this.kweekFunc.like(kweek);
      return;
    }
    // in my profile
    this.kweekService.likeKweek(kweek.id).subscribe(() => {
      this.likeCallBack(kweek);
    });
  }

  likeCallBack(kweek: Kweek): void {
    this.kweeks.forEach(loopKweek => {
      if (loopKweek.id === kweek.id) {
        loopKweek.liked_by_user = true;
        loopKweek.number_of_likes++;
      }
    });
  }

  unlikeDecision(kweek: Kweek): void {
    // not in my profile
    if (this.callCommonFunc) {
      this.kweekFunc.unlike(kweek);
      return;
    }
    // in my profile
    this.kweekService.unlikeKweek(kweek.id).subscribe(() => {
      this.unlikeCallBack(kweek);
    });
  }

  unlikeCallBack(kweek: Kweek): void {
    this.kweeks.forEach(loopKweek => {
      if (loopKweek.id === kweek.id) {
        loopKweek.liked_by_user = false;
        loopKweek.number_of_likes--;
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to click as fast as I want and the callback function just called when the request finished

this is the http request which I use in like:

```
likeKweek(id: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.base}kweeks/like`, { id: id }).pipe(
  map(res => res),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}
```

Comment: why not use async/await?

Comment: U can improve more by adding a debounce handler.
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: You should disable the like/unlike buttons while doing requests first of all.

Comment: I am new with angular, Can you please explain in more detail how to achieve that?

Comment: I added the HTTP request to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a Boolean to check if you are still executing the last request.
for example you can use the next algo.

```
like ( ) {
     if(!busy) {
        busy = true;
        requestfunc => {
            set likes; 
            busy = false;
        }
    }
}
```